# Binary Search Tree vs Array for ordered elements

Tags: algorithm, binary-search-tree, complexity-theory

Consider the scenario where data to be inserted in an array is always in order, i.e. `(1, 5, 12, 20, ...)/A[i] >= A[i-1]` or `(1000, 900, 20, 1, -2, ...)/A[i] <= A[i-1]`.

To support such a dataset, is it more efficient to have a binary search tree or an array.

(Side note: I am just trying to run some naive analysis for a timed hash map of type `(K, T, V)` and the time is always in order. I am debating using `Map<K, BST<T,V>>` vs `Map<K, Array<T,V>>`.)

As I understand, the following costs (worst case) apply—

```
          Array            BST

Space     O(n)             O(n)
Search    O(log n)         O(n)
Max/Min   O(1)             O(1) *
Insert    O(1) **          O(n)
Delete    O(n)             O(n)
```

`*`: Max/Min pointers
`**`: Amortized time complexity

**Q:** I want to be more clear about the question. What kind of data structure should I be using for such a scenario between these two? Please feel free to discuss other data structures like self balancing BSTs, etc.

**EDIT:**

1. Please note I didn't consider the complexity for a balanced binary search tree (RBTree, etc). As mentioned, a *naive* analysis using a binary search tree.
2. Deletion has been updated to O(n) (didn't consider time to search the node).
3. Max/Min for skewed BST will cost `O(n)`. But it's also possible to store pointers for `Max` & `Min` so overall time complexity will be `O(1)`.

Comment: Do specify how you implement BST, search and insert can be optimized to O(logn), also I have doubt reagradings delete in O(1). And how you rpopose to mantain min/max after deletions.

Comment: A balanced BST should be O(log n) for searching as well.

Comment: Insert should be O(log n) on BST. Normal array insert is O(n); how are you getting O(1)?

Comment: Delete should be O(log n) on BST.

Comment: i think since data is always inserted in order, hence O(1) and not O(n) for arrays. But, insertion in BST will still remain O(log n)

Comment: Insertion in BST (unbalanced) in the worst case is `O(n)`. Given the elements are all inserted in order, my BST (if unbalanced) is always skewed towards right.

Comment: but you can write a balancing routine which balances the tree after, say, m insertions. In this way, it can be optimized to O(log n)

Comment: Yes. That's an option.

Answer (score 0):

See below the table which will help you choose. Note that I am assuming 2 things:

1) data will always come in sorted order - you mentioned this i.e. if 1000 is the last data inserted, new data will always be more than 1000 - if data does not come in sorted order, insertion can take O(log n), but deletion will not change

2) your "array" is actually similar to java.util.ArrayList. In short, its length is mutable. (it is actually unfair compare a mutable and an immutable data structure) However, if it is a normal array, your deletion will take amortized O(log n) {O(log n) to search and O(1) to delete, amortized if you need to create new array} and insertion will take amortized O(1) {you need to create new array}

> ```
>           ArrayList         BST
>
>  Space     O(n)             O(n)
>  Search    O(log n)         O(log n) {optimized from O(n)}
>  Max/Min   O(1)             O(log n) {instead of O(1) - you need to traverse till the leaf}
>  Insert    O(1)             O(log n) {optimized from O(n)}
>  Delete    O(log n)         O(log n)
> ```

So, based on this, ArrayList seems better

Comment: Sorry but I do mention `O(n)` for deletion in an array. `O(n)` if you need to create new array but amortized time complexity is still `O(1)` for insertion.

Comment: ok, I think I understand better now. You are creating an array of t elements and initially inserting p elements such that t > p. Hence, amortized  O(1)? Correct me if I am wrong. And please clearly mention that in the question

Comment: So you usually you create an array of size `k` and insert elements till you can. Then you double the size of the array: `2k` and insert more elements. (standard practice for inserting new elements in the array). The only reason why the complexity is amortized `O(1)` is because we always know we need to insert at the last position.

Comment: I know that, which is why I mentioned that ArrayList will perform much better. In a simple array, you need to store the 'lastIndex" after which all locations is useless (data not yet entered in those) and you get only amortized O(1) - ArrayList uses memory efficiently and gives you O(1). Also, as a standard practice, arrays are never used to store incoming data, Lists or Pages are used

Comment: I think we are both on the same page.